# Trying to use an NSTimer

Tags: ios, ios4, nstimer

I'm having a problem getting an NSTimer to work, probably because I don't know how to properly use it (I've tried reading the apple documentation, it didn't help me much). I get a time off of a UIDatePicker and I want the app to call the method when that time is reached. Simple, no? So the code I have is below:

```
-(IBAction)SetButtonPress:(id)sender{
     NSDate *date = [Picker date];
     alarmTimer = [[AlarmTimer alloc] init];
    [alarmTimer runTimer: Picker.date];
}
```

A few things now follow standards, but it still doesn't work. It still gives me a time 6 hours ahead, and when it hits that time, it doesn't do anything.

And the code for the RunTimer method of my alarmTimer class is as follows:

```
-(void)RunTimer: (NSDate *) date
{
NSRunLoop *theLoop = [NSRunLoop currentLoop];
[theLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[timer initWithFireDate:date interval:0 target:self selector:@selector(Play) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
}
```

A few things now follow standards, but it still doesn't work. It still gives me a time 6 hours ahead, and when it hits that time, it doesn't do anything.

And just in case it helps, here is the .h and .m files for the view controller:
.h:

```
//
//  Assignment_1ViewController.h
//  Assignment 1
//
//  Created by Jack Schaible on 11-09-28.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AlarmTimer.h"

@interface Assignment_1ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *SetButton;
    UIDatePicker *Picker;
    UIButton *CancelButton;
    NSString *time;
    AlarmTimer *alarmTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *SetButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *Picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *CancelButton;

- (IBAction)SetButtonPress:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)CancelButtonPress:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m:

```
//
//  Assignment_1ViewController.m
//  Assignment 1
//
//  Created by Jack Schaible on 11-09-28.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Assignment_1ViewController.h"
#import "AlarmTimer.h"

@implementation Assignment_1ViewController
@synthesize Picker;
@synthesize CancelButton;
@synthesize SetButton;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [SetButton release];
    [Picker release];
    [CancelButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setSetButton:nil];
    [self setPicker:nil];
    [self setCancelButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [alarmTimer release];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)SetButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *ndf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    time = [ndf stringFromDate:self.Picker.date];

    alarmTimer = [AlarmTimer alloc];
    [alarmTimer init];

    NSLog(@"Date is: %@", [ndf dateFromString:time]);

    [alarmTimer RunTimer:[ndf dateFromString:time]];
}

- (IBAction)CancelButtonPress:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

And the code for the AlarmTimer class:

```
.h:
//
//  Timer.h
//  Assignment 1
//
//  Created by Jack Schaible on 11-09-28.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AlarmTimer : NSObject {
    NSString *time;
    NSTimer *timer;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}

-(void) RunTimer: (NSDate *)date;
-(void)Play;
-(void)CancelTimer;

@end
```

And finally, the .m:

```
//
//  Timer.m
//  Assignment 1
//
//  Created by Jack Schaible on 11-09-28.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AlarmTimer.h"
@implementation AlarmTimer

-(id) init
{
    if(self == [super init])
    {
        timer = [NSTimer alloc];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Time.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
        NSError *error;
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) RunTimer: (NSDate *)date
{
    [timer initWithFireDate:date interval:86400 target:self selector:@selector(Play) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    NSLog(@"Date is: %@", date);
}

-(void) Play
{
    [player play];
    UIAlertView *aView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Holy Chimes!" message:@"If you didn't hear that..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [aView show];
}

-(void)CancelTimer
{
    time = nil;
}

@end
```

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use NSDateFormatter? try to do it like that:

```
alarmTimer = [AlarmTimer alloc];
[alarmTimer init];

NSLog(@"Date is: %@", self.Picker.date);

[alarmTimer RunTimer: self.Picker.date];
```

Comment: I tried that just now. When I set the time for 12:09, it comes out in the NSLog as 6:09

Comment: Also, I don't think the NSTimer itself isn't working right (if I set the thing to 6 hours previous, it still doesn't run the method)

Comment: ok, try to use NSDateFormatter with ndf.timeZone=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; and setDateFormat: of ndf to the format of self.PickerDate.date. Then get the stringFromDate: Picker.Date. And [alarmTimer RunTimer:[ndf dateFromString:time]];

Answer (score 0):

1. As a rule, do the +alloc and -init together: `Foo *someFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];`. Don't separate the calls as you've done with your `timer` and `alarmTimer` variables. The reason for this is that sometimes the initializer will return a different pointer than what you get from `+alloc`, and when that happens you want to be certain to store that new pointer. I don't know if NSTimer ever does that, but if so you'll have all kinds of trouble with your current code.
2. Don't try to reuse a timer. Once it fires, release it and create a new one when you need to.
3. What's all that craziness in `-SetButtonPress:`? You get a date from a date picker, convert it to a string, and then immediately convert that string back to a date... why?
4. You're using an interval of 24 hours (86400 seconds) for your timer. Are you under the mistaken impression that a timer with a long interval will wake up an app that's in the background? NSTimer relies on the run loop; when the run loop isn't running, the timer isn't working.
5. It'd be somewhat easier to help you if you'd stick to the usual Objective-C convention and name methods starting with lower-case characters, i.e. `-runTimer:` instead of `-RunTimer:`. The same rule applies to instance variables.

Comment: Well I've changed the init/alloc thing, and I've renamed some variables. It still doesn't work. I set it for 2:32 this morning (October 6) and it says in the NSLog that the NSDate is 8:32 on September 28.

Comment: So, what time zone are you in?

Comment: Mountain (US & Canada) GMT-0700

Comment: NSDate always uses GMT, so if you log a date directly you're going to get a time in GMT. Use a properly configured date formatter to print the time in your local time. There's no need, however, to convert the date to a string and then convert that back to a date -- that's just a waste of time. You only need to use the formatter when you want to display the date. For logging purposes, it's probably easier to log the date object itself and convert from GMT in your head.

Comment: Note that we're still observing daylight savings time, and MDT is UTC-6, so 2:32 GMT corresponds to 8:32 MDT. I'm not sure why you get Sept 28 instead of Oct 8; it could be your choice of calendar or something else in the way you've configured your date picker.